# Выровнить текст по центру по высоте в TextView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнять текст по центру TextView по высоте? 
Как работает Gravity.CENTER меня не устраивает. Как видно на рисунке на черном TextView, текст aaaaa не симметричен.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:text="aaaaa"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: center_horizontal для gravity и paddingTop рассчитайте, если не планируете менять размер textView, а если планируете, то можно будет программно менять, но все же костыли

Comment: Не получается paddingTop правильно рассчитать, так как внутри textView есть какие-то отступы..  Вот так вот не правильно получается:  int padd_top;
                Rect bounds = new Rect();
                textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
                padd_top = (textView.getMeasuredHeight() - bounds.height()) / 2;

Comment: Как правильно рассчитать paddingTop ?

Comment: Он симметричен, потому что могут быть буквы в верхнем регистре.

Comment: Style-7, так в том то и вопрос, что выравнивать исходя из текста, сейчас-то нет этих букв с верхним регистром, или цифр...